# Creating VM using AzureRm Module taking too much time

Tags: azure, powershell-4.0, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rm

I am using AzureRm Module to create VM on Azure. For that I am running **"New-AzureRmVM"** command. But it is taking too much time (12 minutes approx.) to create a VM and not returning the Shell prompt between that time frame. Is there any other alternative?

I've also run same command using **"-AsJob"** switch which runs by command in background and return me the Shell prompt but in that case how can i check if my VM created successfully or not and what's the output of that command?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Get-Job` and `Receive-Job` cmdlets to check progress. You can also use `Wait-Job` to wait for the job to finish.

ps. it shouldnt take 12 minutes to create vm.
pps. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs/

Comment: It is taking 12 minutes time to give prompt back. I can see VM creation started after 1 minute of running command but not getting prompt back instantly.

Comment: what "it"? it should give prompt back instantly with `-asJob`

Comment: "It" refers to "create vm" command and I am talking about without -asjob switch. Please try it before commenting anything here.

Comment: Please try without -asjob switch.

Comment: ok, i misread your comment, sorry, vm creation take 2-3 minutes without `-asjob` with ssd, 5-7 minutes without it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you will take less time if you select a bigger size such as Standard_A2 or a bigger size then it. Of curse, it will cost more money. HHD disk or SSD disk also cost different time to create VM. Just proved as the comment in the [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250060/why-cant-i-create-azure-vms-with-terraform-smoothly/51259722#51259722).